# Pra que serve o segundo parâmetro de array_keys?

Tags: php

Estava dando uma mexida no sublime text e me deparei algo que não esperava quando fui digitar a função `array_keys`

```
 array_keys(arg, search_value, strict);
```

Fiz o teste e realmente o segundo parâmetro funciona.

Qual é a finalidade dele, afinal?

Comment: O segundo parâmetro não ia funcionar pq? pq é php, vc ta zoando xD?

Comment: +1 pelo sublime

Comment: Usei esse comando semana passada. E o `array_key_exists` também.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro faz a função retornar o index das posições onde determinado valor se encontra.

Por exemplo:

> ```
> $array = array("teste", "algo", "outra coisa", "teste", "teste");
> var_dump(array_keys($array, "teste"));
> ```

Vai retornar o seguinte:

> ```
> array(3) {
>   [0]=>
>   int(0)
>   [1]=>
>   int(3)
>   [2]=>
>   int(4)
> }
> ```

Pois o nome "teste" está presente nas posições 0, 3 e 4 do array.

Coloquei uma demonstração https://3v4l.org/MWBAi

Answer (score 4):

[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), devolve todas as chaves de um array. QUando segundo argumento é informado ele retorna todas as ocorrências daquele valor, me parece uma versão que retorna multiplos valores de [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

```
<?php
$arr = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_keys($arr, "blue"));//retorna uma array com 0,3,4


$key = array_search("blue", $arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($key);//retorna apenas 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Serve para filtrar os índices que serão retornados - [Conforme a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php)

Parâmetros ¶

> **input**
>
> Um array contendo chaves a serem retornadas.
>
> **search_value**
>
> Se especificado, então somente chaves contendo estes valores são retornado.
>
> **strict**
>
> No PHP 5, este parâmetro determina se a comparação é rígida (===) durante a busca.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo o que entendi ele retorna apenas os valores que você especificar, servindo assim como uma opção de procura mesmo, como o nome sugere.`

```
<?php
   $a=array("Volvo"=>"XC90","BMW"=>"X5","Toyota"=>"Highlander");
   print_r(array_keys($a,"Highlander"));
?>
```

Ou seja, neste exemplo ele irá apenas mostrar os resultados que contenham o valor *"Highlander"*, portando serviria como um *strpos*, só que já lhe retornando os valores sem precisar percorrer o array.